# Find a link whose href matches

Tags: jquery

I have a link like:

`<a href="#slide1">Slide 1</a>`

And I want to find it like so:

`$('ul.dots li a').attr('href').is('#' + id).parents('li').toggleClass('selected');`

the id variable would be something like: `#slide1` including the hash. However it does not work... Any ideas on how best to do this? I also tried: `$('ul.dots li a[href=#' + id + ']').parents('li').toggleClass('selected');` but doesn't work either...

Can anyone help. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the attribute selector the quotes around the attribute value are required.

Try something like:

```
$('a[href="#' + id + '"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem would likely be including the # character in your `id` variable but also adding an additional one in your jQuery selector. If you want links where the `href` attributes value is '#slide1' then you don't want to be looking for '##slide1'. Simply use `id` rather than `'#' + id` and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

make it simple

```
$("a").filter(function(){
  return $(this).attr('href') == "#" + whatever;
});
```